# Problem with differentiation question

Tags: implicit-differentiation

The question is as follows:

> Let $l$ be any tangent to the curve $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{k}$, where $k > 0$. Show that the sum of the $x$-intercept and the $y$-intercept of $l$ is $k$.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Cettt I am writing this on my mobile so it is a bit tough to get across. But I have tried brute forcing it to find the gradient in terms of x and k. And then trying to force out an equation for the tangent line and add its resultant x and y intercepts together to simplify it to k. But that does not work as there are too many unknown.

Comment: @Cettt I have also tried imagining the tangent as the hypothenuse of a triangle beneath the curve and trying to prove that both lengths of that triangle have to add up to constant k but I am having no success with that either. Any guiding comments will be much appreciated

Comment: You won't need trigonometry.  Do you know how to take the derivative of the equation of above, with respect to x, using implicit differentiation?  If so, that's your first step.  Please show that step in your question, to show your progress.

Comment: @Joe Actually I have solved it already. It was a lot easier than I thought. I am still on mobile so formatting is an issue though.

Comment: Great!  Yes, often on this site, when someone asks a question that isn't very difficult, without showing any independent progress, the first thing they'll be asked is to show what they've tried so far.

Comment: @Joe Yea I know. I wanted to show it but formatting my attempts are difficult on mobile. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already solved the problem I leave you an answer to be compared with yours.

By differentiating $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{k}$ we get $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}=0$. Hence $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}}$ and the tangent line at $(x,y)$ is
$$Y-y=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}}(X-x)$$
that is
$$\frac{X}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{Y}{\sqrt{y}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{k}.$$
Now it should be easy to verify that the sum of the $x$-intercept and the $y$-intercept is
$$\sqrt{k}\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{k}\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{k}\cdot \sqrt{k}=k.$$

Comment: Yep! this was my solution

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $k=1$ (otherwise, rescale). Then let $x=\cos^4t,y=\sin^4t.$

A tangent has the equation

$$\frac{x-\cos^4t}{-4\sin t\cos^3t}=\frac{y-\sin^2t}{4\cos t\sin^3t}$$ or $$\frac x{\cos^2t}+\frac y{\sin^2t}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

To avoid implicit differentiation.

We move $\sqrt{x}$ to the RHS and square both sides:
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{k} \Rightarrow y=x-2\sqrt{xk}+k$$
Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be the tangent point. The tangent line equation is:
$$\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\underbrace{1-\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{x_0}}}_{y'(x_0)}$$
The intercepts $(\color{blue}x,\color{red}0),(\color{red}0,\color{blue}y)$ are:
$$\frac{\color{red}0-y_0}{\color{blue}x-x_0}=1-\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{x_0}}\Rightarrow \color{blue}x=x_0+\frac{-y_0\sqrt{x_0}}{\underbrace{\sqrt{x_0}-\sqrt{k}}_{-\sqrt{y_0}}}=x_0+\sqrt{x_0y_0}\\
\frac{\color{blue}y-y_0}{\color{red}0-x_0}=1-\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{x_0}} \Rightarrow \color{blue}y=y_0+\frac{-x_0(\overbrace{\sqrt{x_0}-\sqrt{k}}^{-\sqrt{y_0}})}{\sqrt{x_0}}=y_0+\sqrt{x_0y_0}\\
\color{blue}x+\color{blue}y=x_0+y_0+2\sqrt{x_0y_0}=(\sqrt{x_0}+\sqrt{y_0})^2=k.$$